# How to migrate old data to django-quill-editor

Tags: django, django-admin, django-generic-relations

I had a `textField` in my model before. Now I want to upgrade it to a rich text field using [Django Quill Editor](https://pypi.org/project/django-quill-editor/). But I am unable the migrate the old data.

I tried to just copy the text inside the `quillfield` in a management command but it gives `QuillParseError` then I looked the databse and figured that the fields are stored like:

```
{"delta":"{\"ops\":[{\"insert\":\"text\\n\"}]}","html":"<p>text</p>"}
```

in the database.
I kept the delta empty and only filled the html. the html appeared in the database but not in the admin. I then tried to fabricate the ops. without filling the html and that failed too. I can only think of fabricating the whole object but that would be a bit difficult. I was wondering if there is any sane way to migrate html/text data to quillfield or any other richtext editor.

Comment: fill in both delta and html, like in the example you quoted

Answer (score 0):

I have added this value as a default for the new fields in old models and it worked:

`default='{"delta":{"ops":[{"insert":"test"}]},"html":"<p>test</p>"}'`

Comment: Thank you. But when the text becomes more complex it won't work. We ended up moving to tinymce and it has been working great so far.